# IObservable<> through CombineLatest doesn't fire

Tags: c#, system.reactive

When I put a `breakpoint` on `current` or `normal`, they get called. However, if I put a `breakpoint` on the line below it where I `CombineLatest`, it never gets called.

`FastPeriod` = 60 seconds. `SlowPeriod` = 120 seconds.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
public class SpikeIndicator : IDisposable, IIndicator
{
....
public IObservable<IndicatorValues> Stream { get; private set; }


private void IntializeSpikeStream()
{
    var current = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FastPeriod))
         .Select(_ => GetLastPrice());

    var normal = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SlowPeriod))
         .Select(_ => GetLastPrice()).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FastPeriod));

    var stream = current.CombineLatest(normal, (a, b) => (a - b) / a)
        .Where(diffPercent => diffPercent != PercentDiff)
        .Select(ratePercent => new SpikeIndicatorValues { PercentRate = ratePercent }).Publish();

    spikeSubscription = stream.Connect();

    Stream = stream;            
}

public void Dispose()
{
    spikeSubscription?.Dispose();
}

public IObservable<IndicatorValues> GetObservable()
{
    return this.Stream;
}
...
}
```

Comment: This is where a [mcve] is useful. Without being able to copy, paste, and run your code it is hard to know for sure what is going wrong.

Comment: We don't know what `PercentDiff` is. We don't know what the type of `GetLastPrice()` is - if it's `int` then you're doing integer maths in the `CombineLatest` which might be giving you unexpected results.

Comment: @Enigmativity you mean `diffPercent` ? :) ... but yeah ... you're right ...

Comment: I would also expect that the comparison should be `diffPercent >= PercentDiff` rather than `diffPercent != PercentDiff`. Is that causing the query not to produce values?

Comment: @Noctis - No, I meant `PercentDiff`. Can you please provide a [mcve]? (Please read the page that links to carefully.)

Comment: @Noctis - If I make some good assumptions regarding the above questions then your code works. You need to update the question to answer my issues and then an answer can be provided. Right now I can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: The question is not what the Percentdidd should be, It is that this code never executes. The reason for having the pd > 9 i to ensure it fires for debgging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Not sure how much of these changes I need, but this works.

```
private void IntializeSpikeStream()
    {
        var current = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FastPeriod))
             .Select(_ => GetLastPrice()).Publish();

        var normal = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SlowPeriod))
             .Select(_ => GetLastPrice()).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FastPeriod)).Publish();


        ts1Subscription1 = current.Connect();
        ts1Subscription2 = normal.Connect(); 

        var stream = current.CombineLatest(normal, (a, b) => (a - b) / a)
            .Where(diffPercent => diffPercent != PercentDiff)
            .Select(ratePercent => new SpikeIndicatorValues { PercentRate = ratePercent }).Publish();

        spikeSubscription = stream.Connect();

        Stream = stream;            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        spikeSubscription?.Dispose();
        ts1Subscription1?.Dispose();
        ts1Subscription2?.Dispose();
    }
```